# Unabel to login on Linkedin Organization Page

Tags: linkedin-api, make.com, integromat-apps

I created an app on Linkedin Developer to be able to automatically publish Instagram posts on the Linkedin profile of the ViaggiAtelier organization.
Even after entering all the correct credentials I get a 401 error:
{"message":"The request failed due to failure of a previous request.","code":"SC424","suberrors":[{"message":"[unauthorized_scope_error] Scope "r_liteprofile" is not authorized for your application","name":"InvalidConfigurationError"}]}

I've already heard from Make, but they referred me to Linkedin:
Thank you for taking the time to share your feedback. After carefully investigating your situation, it has come to our attention that the profile scope r_liteprofile may be the source of the error you are encountering, as you may have noticed from the error message.

To assist you in resolving this issue, we recommend seeking guidance on how to connect to your LinkedIn developer app. We understand that this may be frustrating, so we suggest reaching out to LinkedIn support and sharing the error message with them. They will be able to assist you with this specific issue.

Currently, Make is only able to send an authentication request using your LinkedIn credentials, but it seems that LinkedIn is not accepting them.

Please reach out to LinkedIn support by sharing the following error of your developer app:

{"message":"The request failed due to failure of a previous request.","code":"SC424","suberrors":[{"message":"[unauthorized_scope_error] Scope "r_liteprofile" is not authorized for your application","name":"InvalidConfigurationError"}]}

I'm trying to automatically post IG Image post to linkedin organization page